# Django choices vs store in data base

Tags: django, django-models

What is better to do in case you want to set fixed choices in a model, but they are too numerous?

I will put an example with countries, is not exactly my case, but is with geographic locations:

This:

```
COUNTRY_CHOICES = (
    ('A', 'ARGENTINA'),
    # 200 more countries
)
# model field
my_field = models.CharField(
    choices = COUNTRY_CHOICES
)
```

Vs store every value in database.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all are they fixed? Furthermore another question is: do you want to be able to query on these.

Comment: Yes they are fixed. No I don't need to query, they are just for info display.

Comment: Well sinceit is a design decision, there is no "perfect" answer. Both have advantages. By using choices, most database systems will *not* validate that the field contains valid information. But the point is of course if you want that?

Comment: I was wondering on performance issues, if there's a difference between them.

Comment: That can be the case, if there is no `select_related`. If one queries without that, it will result in an extra query, per `object.my_field` call. WIth a `.select_related` I think the overhead is negligable, especially if you need the display, Python will have to do a lookup itself, and this will typically result in approximately the same performance.

Answer (score 1):

For DB storage-wise, I would suggest that you have separate class for the countries and have a FK in your actual model.